# jQuery ajax call throws an HTTP 302

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement a jQuery Autocomplete where the Autocomplete gets its data from a ajax source. However, for some reason when I make the call it results in a 302 which in turn results in a 404.

This is what I have:

**In functions.php:**

```
function my_ajax_foo() {
  die("OK");
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_foo', 'my_ajax_foo' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_foo', 'my_ajax_foo' );
```

**My Javascript:**

```
function onGetData(term, callback) {
  jQuery.post( "http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", {
    action: "my_ajax_foo",
    cookie: encodeURIComponent(document.cookie),
    term: term
  },
  function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
  } );
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#my_input_field").autocomplete( { source:onGetData } );
});
```

All the Javascript is loaded correctly. When I type in the Autocomplete input box the ajax call is made but I can see in Firebug that the call results in a HTTP 302.

When I call the `http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` simply from the browser URL I get a `-1` returned so I know that the URL exists.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: when I put the same code in my functions.php and run `jQuery.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',{action:'my_ajax_foo'},function(response){console.log(response);});` in Chrome's console (which is just like firebug), it works exactly as expected. I would first try doing that to remove all the other variables. If that still doesn't work, my hunch would be that something is interfering with the request (could be a plugin, htaccess, etc)

Comment: After posting my comment, I thought "well, duh, I'll just open admin-ajax.php and see what would redirect the request", and you know what I found? Nothing. So I'd bet top dollar it's a plugin. Do you have any plugins which restricts access? Anything with user roles, site members, etc?

Comment: What happens when you visit the admin-ajax with your action as a GET variable: http://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_ajax_foo&term=term

Comment: How about using a relative path instead of an absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, just skip that:

```
 cookie: encodeURIComponent(document.cookie)
```

There's no need to post any cookies on XHR - the browser handles that.

Well, how about something like that instead (untested):

```
data:{'term':encodeURIComponent($.term)}
```

Most easy is to use FireBug, open Net panel and inspect both HTTP headers.